# Adding Columns to DimDate

Tags: sql

trying to add 4 columns to existing DimDate table. Column names: [isCurrentFinancialYear], [isPreviousFinancialYear], [isPreviousQuarter],[isCurrentQuarter].

For isCurrentFinancialYear, used the below logic

```
update [TABLE NAME]
set [isCurrentFinancialYear] = 'Y'
WHERE [Date] >= MAX([FirstDayOfFinancialYear]) AND [Date] <= MAX([LastDayOfFinancialYear])
```

However, it gives error saying:

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Why is your table named "DimDate", exactly?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?